# Unable to add / send Text to a XCUIElementSecureTextField using Appium inspector

Tags: ios, appium-ios, xcuitest, appium-inspector, xcuielement

I'm using Appium Inspector to access the page source of an iOS App. I'm able to send Texts to *XCUIElementTextField* but not to the *SecuretypeField*. Even the keyboard is not showing up when I tried to click on the element.

note: I'm using the Sauce Labs device

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the 'Show password' button and the XCUIElementSecureTextField will be changed to a simple XCUIElementTextField, enabling you to enter any text.

I also noticed some issues with sending characters to the XCUIElementSecureTextField and the only solution I found was to change the field type as I described above.

Comment: Thanks for the response :-).  I don't have a show password button. But I noticed that the send text in Appium inspector is working but somehow the added text is not visible in the secureTextField (weird!!). But When I enter manually in the real device, I'm able to see the text.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).